# binary representation of unsigned int arg

Tags: c

the number of occurrences in the binary representation of its unsigned integer argument.

For example, the number 183 is 0b10110111 and there are three occurrences of 11.

Can someone explain or elaborate(with examples) what this means?

Comment: Is this something that you need to write? No standard function exists like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  People tend to look askance at questions that simply ask for code, rather than questions that show some code that genuinely tries to solve the problem and needs some assistance.

Comment: I think he pasted an ungrammatical chunk of the homework problem, which was not good.  But the question seems to be asking for an explanation of the problem, not code. He/she could be having a language problem with the word "occurrences."

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Start the count at 0.  Look at each consecutive pair of bits.  If they're 11, increment the count.  If they're not, don't.

In your example 10110111, the consecutive pairs are

```
10 01 11 10 01 11 11
```

Three of these are 11, so return 3.

If you need to implement this, the easiest approach is probably to look at the 2 least significant bits to see if they're 11.  If so, increment the counter.  Then shift the whole number right one bit and loop.  The loop can stop when you've shifted all the 1's out so the number is 0.  At this point the counter will hold the answer. All this can be done in 3 or 4 lines of code, which you really ought to write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It counts how many couple of bits (with overlap) are set in the unsigned int.

More technically, for every i-th bit of the argument, with `0 <= i <= 30`, if `i`-th bit is set and `(i+1)`-th bit is set then you have a couple. Count all of them and you are done.